# Can I use R to look at the frequency of values appearing in each column in a table?

Tags: r, netezza, data-analysis

I'm a beginner with R, and I want to know if I can use it to get a comprehensive look at my data. Specifically, I have a table in a database containing 650 columns. I would like to know what are the distinct values for each column, and how many of each value occur in the column.

For example, if my table looked like this:

```
ID   DATA1    DATA2    DATA3    DATA4
1    A        42       FORD     QQ
2    B        42       ACURA    66
3    C        (null)   (null)   88
4    A        (null)   FORD     QQ
```

I would want to know the following:

```
Column DATA1 has the following distribution:
    Value    Count
    A        2
    B        1
    C        1

Column DATA2 has the following distribution:
    Value    Count
    (null)   2
    42       2

...
```

That way I can figure out which columns are (null) for a large portion of rows in the table.

The table is in a netezza database, and I have already figured out how to connect to, and run queries against, the database. My question is how could run this type of analysis with R.

If there's a way to output a visualization, for example in a stacked bar graph with a bar for each column and each "piece" of the stack representing a value, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Well the tabulation can be done with reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(variable, value) %>%
  summarize(frequency = n() )
```